# why react props are passed undefined to the child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have get some data from db , when I console log them it works nice. 
and also when I stringfy the passed props are OK and displayed on the screen as they are expected.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { URL } from '../../../../config'
import Header from './header'

class NewArticle extends Component {
    state = {
        article: [],
        team: []
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(`${ URL }/articles?id=${ this.props.match.params.id }`)
        .then( res => {
            let article = res.data[ 0 ]
            console.log( res.data[ 0 ] )
            //{
                //     author: "John Secada",
                //     date: "10/12/2018",
            // }           
            axios.get( `${ URL }/teams?id=${ article.team }` )
            .then( res => {
                this.setState({
                    article,
                    team: res.data[0]
                })
                console.log( res.data[0] )
                // {
                //     id: 3,
                //     logo: "nets.png",
                //     name: "Nets",
                //     poll: "false",
                //     stats: {wins: 23, defeats: 12}
                // }
            } )
        } )
    }
    render(){
        let article = this.state.article
        let team = this.state.team
        return(
            <div>
                 <Header
                    teamData={ team }
                    date={ article.date }
                    author={ article.author }
                    />
                { JSON.stringify(article,team) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default NewArticle
```

the Header component which recieves the props:

```
import React from 'react'
const Header = props => {
    return (
        <div>    
            { console.log( props) }
            {/* {teamData: Array(0), date: undefined, author: undefined} */}    
        </div>
    )
}
export default Header
```

So why they are undefined, when I pass them as props to a Header component?

Comment: First use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount` for side effects(api call), on first render `<Header />` will not have `article` data, it is after api data resolves, data is available, you need to check if `article` data is available and only then render `<Header />` component.

Comment: Also `componentWillMount ` is a legacy life cycle method, you should not use these methods as they will not work after React V17
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you have async request and when Header is being mounted you don't have this data yet.

Try this:

```
   render(){
        const article = this.state.article
        const team = this.state.team

        if(!article && !article.date && !article.author) {
          return null;
        }

        if(!team) {
          return null;
        }

        return(
            <div>
                 <Header
                    teamData={ team }
                    date={ article.date }
                    author={ article.author }
                    />
                { JSON.stringify(article,team) }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: I also suggest to not use ```componentWillMount``` as it will be deprecated. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount

Answer (score 5):

Inside the *componentWillMount* you are using *axios* which returns a promise and is asynchronous. The problem is that you are rendering the `<Header/>` before the data is fetched from the API. To Avoid this you can update your `render` function like this.

```
function render() {
 let article = this.state.article;
 let team = this.state.team;
 return (
  <div>
   {team.length ? (
    <Header teamData={team} date={article.date} author={article.author} />
    ) : (
    'Loading Data...'
   )}
  {JSON.stringify(article, team)}
  </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, [@Evghenii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652909/why-react-props-are-passed-undefined#56653013) 's answer is correct.

Here's the more smart and recommended approach to handle conditional rendering.

You can use Higher Order Components to handle conditional rendering in reactjs.

For more details: [Higher Order Components with Conditional Rendering in React](https://www.robinwieruch.de/gentle-introduction-higher-order-components/).