# ReactJS: how to access prop from child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-props

I'm learning React.js and I'm trying to make a website with the pokeAPI.

For one of my widget I want to display several pokemons with their statistics.

To do this, I have a main component that will call the API and populate my state array, then call a CardPokemon child component within a map to display each one of the pokemon.

Here is my problem, in my web console I can see that my different pokemons stats state array are filling up, but in the render of my main component the values of my array remain "undefined".

I tried to implement the first answer to this question: [why react props are passed undefined to the child component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652909/why-react-props-are-passed-undefined-to-the-child-component?answertab=votes#tab-top) in my code, but I still have the same problem, the values of my array remain "undefined" in the render.

I put a part of my code here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class CardPokemon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Card">
        <div className="Card__img">
          <img src={this.props.pokemonImgProp[this.props.id]} alt="" />
        </div>
         ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class GenerationPokemonStat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemonNameListAPI: [],
      pokemonImgAPI: []
      ...
    };
  }

  searchAllPokemon = () => {
    let number = 151; //for the 151 first pokemon
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemonByGeneration/allPokemonGen/${number}`)
      .then(res => {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
          let copyNameArray = this.state.pokemonNameListAPI.slice();
          copyNameArray[i] = res.data.results[i].name;
          this.setState({ pokemonNameListAPI: copyNameArray })
          
Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemonByGeneration/one_pokemon_gen/${this.state.pokemonNameListAPI[i]}`)
            .then(response => {

              let copyImgArray = this.state.pokemonImgAPI.slice();
              copyImgArray[i] = response.data.sprites.front_default;
              this.setState({ pokemonImgAPI: copyImgArray });
      
              ...

              //everything display normally in web console here
              console.log(response);
              console.log(this.state.pokemonNameAPI[i]);
              console.log(this.state.pokemonImgAPI[i]);
            })
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    let pokemonNameListAPI = this.state.pokemonNameListAPI;
    let pokemonImgAPI = this.state.pokemonImgAPI;

    //appears to be undefined in web console
    console.log(this.state.pokemonImgAPI[0]);

    if(!pokemonNameListAPI) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.searchAllPokemon}>Search Pokemon</button>
          {pokemonNameListAPI[151] === undefined ? <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loading...</h1> : (
            <>
              <div className="grid-container">
                {pokemonNameListAPI.map((i) => {

                  //this console.log show me undefined for pokemonImgAPI[i]
                  console.log(pokemonImgAPI[i]);

                  return <CardPokemon
                    key={i}
                    id={i}
                    pokemonImgProp={pokemonImgAPI}
                  />
                })}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default GenerationPokemonStat;
```

**Code edited but still not working**
I've try to implement what you told me but it still not working, am I doing it the good way ?

```
function CardPokemon({ pokemonStatProp }) {
  return (
    <div className="Card">
      <div className="Card__img">
        <img src={pokemonStatProp[1]} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div className="Card__name">
        {pokemonStatProp[0]}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class GenerationPokemonStat extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pokemonNameAPI: [],
      pokemonImgAPI: [],
      pokemonLoading: true
    };
  }

  searchAllPokemon = () => {
    this.setState({ pokemonLoading: true });
    let number = 10;
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemonByGeneration/allPokemonGen/${number}`)
      .then(res => {

        let nameArray = this.state.pokemonNameListAPI.slice();
        let imgArray = this.state.pokemonImgAPI.slice();

        for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
          nameArray[i] = res.data.results[i].name;
          Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemonByGeneration/one_pokemon_gen/${nameArray[i]}`)
            .then(response => {

              imgArray[i] = response.data.sprites.front_default;
            })
        }
        this.setState({ pokemonNameListAPI: nameArray });
        this.setState({ pokemonImgAPI: imgArray });
        this.setState({ pokemonLoading: false });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.searchAllPokemon}>Search Pokemon</button>
          {this.state.pokemonLoading === true ? <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loading...</h1> : (
            <>
              <div className="grid-container">
                {this.state.pokemonNameListAPI.map((i) => {
                  let pokemonStat = [];
                  pokemonStat[0] = this.state.pokemonNameListAPI[i];
                  pokemonStat[1] = this.state.pokemonImgAPI[i];
                  return <CardPokemon
                    key={i}
                    pokemonStatProp={pokemonStat}
                  />
                })}
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default GenerationPokemonStat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try reading state immediately after setting it as state updates may be performed asynchronously (see [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)). In your case this may mean the second axios call is not getting the parameter you expect and returning a null result.

Try this:

```js
searchAllPokemon = () => {
    let number = 151; //for the 151 first pokemon
    Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemonByGeneration/allPokemonGen/${number}`)
      .then(res => {
        
        // Could also use computed property name.
        var combined: {name, img}[] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
          
          combined.push({name: res.data.results[i].name});

 Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getPokemonByGeneration/one_pokemon_gen/${res.data.results[i].name}`)
            .then(response => {

              // Have an img for a name. 
              // Find the array item matching this name so we can 
              // set the img value. 
              // This requires you to have the pokemon name in results.
              // If using computed property we could use bracket 
              // notation here instead of find.
              let c = combined.find(f => f.name === response.data.sprites.front.name);
               c.img = response.data.sprites.front_default;
              ...

            })
        }
        
        this.setState({combinedAPI: combined})
      })
  }
```

Also, keep in mind that whenever you update state react will detect the state change and cause the component to refresh. You are currently performing two setState calls within a loop. I would consider constructing your axios results into local variables and setState, once, outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've try to implement with your way but I still have the same problem, am I doing it the right way please ? I've had my new code but my edit need to be accepted. Thanks for your help

Comment: Check this line "imgArray[i] = response.data.sprites.front_default;".

Comment: Axios calls are async by default so its possible for the for loop to complete before axios returns a result. The value of "i" could be anything. Is the name unique? I will update code above to show possible workaround.

Comment: I started from the beginning of my code using your method and I can pass my prop now, thank you very much for your help and your time :)

Comment: @vincent - glad to help. please mark the answer as accepted. thanks